# Parse Issue Expected Identifier in Main.m

Tags: xcode, parsing, identifier

In this section of code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {


        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate]));
    }
}
```

The debugger says there is a Parse Issue and Expected Identifier. When i test the app in the simulator, it crashes immediately. How can I make my app run in the simulator without taking me to main.m?

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting `[AppDelegate]` to do? That's not valid syntax. You probably meant `[AppDelegate class]`, although the construct `NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])` is pretty pointless when you can just type `@"AppDelegate"`.